# Regex to match meta description tags that are containing non white space characters

Tags: html, regex, meta-tags

Hi you smart RegEx Magicians out there!

I am trying to create a RegEx that matches the meta description tag(s) in my source code that are not empty or not just containing white spaces.

So e.g. this should match:

```
<meta name="description" content="This is my super great meta description &amp; I love it so much!"/>
<meta name="description" content=" This is my super great meta description &amp; I love it so much!"/>
<meta name="description" content="This is my super great meta description &amp; I love it so much! "/>
```

This e.g. shouldn't match:

```
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="description" content=" "/>
<meta name="description" content="  "/>
<meta name="description" content="
"/>
```

So far I have come up with this, but of course that is not enough and I don't really know how to replace the wildcard...

```
#<\s*meta[^>]\s*name\s*=\s*("|')description("|')\s*content\s*=\s*("|').*("|')?\/?[^>]*>#i
```

Anyone who can help?

Much love and appreciation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems overly complex and not right.

You can use this `(?!\s*")` negative look ahead to reject the match if content attribute just contains zero or more whitespace characters. Over all regex would be this,

```
<meta\s+name="description"\s+content="(?!\s*").*"\/>
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH5QlW/1)**

Comment: Thank you so much. I have slightly adjusted it to this now: 
    <meta\s+name="description"\s+content="(?!\s*").*"\s*\/>

Comment: @Joanna: Yes, that's perfect as that will now allow optional space before ending of tag.